# get data single table form parent child query pos_parent_id table as child id

Tags: php, mysql

my table name is `forum_posts`

[image]

I will get data as this first `parent_id` after it sub child id

means `post_id`

40 
41 
42 
43 
44 
48 (Here it post_parent_id = 44) 
49 (Here it post_parent_id = 44) 
45 
47 (Here it post_parent_id = 45) 
46 
50 (Here it post_parent_id = 46)

can you help how it's possible

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(post_id, IF(post_parent_id = 0, '', CONCAT('(Here it post_parent_id =',,')') 
FROM forum_posts
```